# Why Do I keep getting NaN?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

These are my codes. I don't know why I keep getting NaN? Please help me on this one. My textbox value comes from a dropdown that whatever the user chooses, a corresponding value will appear on the textbox that's why i used `value=""` I don't know if its the part that I got wrong. Please tell me how to deal with this NaN.

**JS**

```
function subtotal(){
        var as = $("#as").val();
        var txt1 = $('#sff').val();
        var txt2 = $('#osf').val();
        var d = 0;
        var e = 0;
        var f = 0;
        var g = 0;

        var a = parseFloat(as, 10);
        var b = parseFloat(txt1, 10);
        var c = parseFloat(txt2, 10);

        if ($('#cbx3').is(":checked")) {
            d = parseFloat($("#cbx3").val(), 10);
        }
        if ($('#cbx4').is(":checked")) {
            e = parseFloat($("#cbx4").val(), 10);
        }
        if ($('#cbx5').is(":checked")) {
            f = parseFloat($("#cbx5").val(), 10);
        }
        if ($('#cbx6').is(":checked")) {
            g = parseFloat($("#cbx6").val(), 10);
        }
        var total = a + b + c + d + e + f + g;

        $('#st').val(total.toFixed(2)); 
        }
function grandtotal(){
var x = document.getElementById("st").value;
var y = document.getElementById("shppng").value;

var sum = parseFloat(x, 10)+ parseFloat(y, 10);
$("#gt").val(sum.toFixed(2));
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="sff" placeholder="$0.00" value="" style="float:left;"/>
<input type="text" id="osf" placeholder="$0.00" value="" style="float:left;"/>
<select id="as" style="margin: 3px 0 0 55px; width:48%; position: absolute; float: left;">
       <option value="99.00">$99.00/</option>
       <option value="178.20">$178.20</option>
       <option value="241.56">$241.56</option>
       <option value="292.24">$292.24</option>
       <option value="332.80">$332.80</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbx4" value="69.00"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbx5" value="35.00"/>
input type="checkbox" id="cbx6" value="39.00"/>
```

Comment: Adding a [jsFidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/) will help a lot.

Comment: Please provide complete code (preferably minimal) that actually reproduces the issue. The code posted does not do anything: the functions defined are not called anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Specify default value.

```
<input type="text" id="sff" placeholder="$0.00" value="0" style="float:left;"/>
<input type="text" id="osf" placeholder="$0.00" value="0" style="float:left;"/>
```

Comment: If this is not then please provide more html code in your question and but I am sure that error is you are reading text value rather than num. It may possible that you have combined symbol and value and try to convert to value later on so

Comment: i'm trying to convert that text to float.

Comment: You have to check how your text look like or atleast put text in console.log and provide here so it will easy to diagnosis.I am not able to see cbx3.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `a`, `b` or `c` can be blank so

```js
function subtotal() {
  var as = $("#as").val();
  var txt1 = $('#sff').val();
  var txt2 = $('#osf').val();
  var d = 0;
  var e = 0;
  var f = 0;
  var g = 0;

  var a = parseFloat(as, 10) || 0;
  var b = parseFloat(txt1, 10) || 0;
  var c = parseFloat(txt2, 10) || 0;

  if ($('#cbx3').is(":checked")) {
    d = parseFloat($("#cbx3").val(), 10);
  }
  if ($('#cbx4').is(":checked")) {
    e = parseFloat($("#cbx4").val(), 10);
  }
  if ($('#cbx5').is(":checked")) {
    f = parseFloat($("#cbx5").val(), 10);
  }
  if ($('#cbx6').is(":checked")) {
    g = parseFloat($("#cbx6").val(), 10);
  }
  var total = a + b + c + d + e + f + g;

  $('#st').val(total.toFixed(2));
}

function grandtotal() {
  var x = document.getElementById("st").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("shppng").value;

  var sum = parseFloat(x, 10) + parseFloat(y, 10);
  $("#gt").val(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="sff" placeholder="$0.00" value="" style="float:left;" />
<input type="text" id="osf" placeholder="$0.00" value="" style="float:left;" />
<select id="as">
  <option value="99.00">$99.00/</option>
  <option value="178.20">$178.20</option>
  <option value="241.56">$241.56</option>
  <option value="292.24">$292.24</option>
  <option value="332.80">$332.80</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbx4" value="69.00" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbx5" value="35.00" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbx6" value="39.00" />
<br />
<input id="st" />
<input id="gt" />
<br />
<input type="button" value="Total" onclick="subtotal(); grandtotal();" />
```